# Test-Path if statement conditions not working

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make my script go through an excel sheet and print out any results where it finds no file, however, the if statement does not work.I will need the if statement condition to work in the future to make sure if there is a png and a jpeg file, or a jpeg and a png for the staff member, it wont just crash and i instead and can direct it to try a different file.
Maybe I am doing something wrong? I have tried it with 1 True or False but ideally I need to check it against all 3.

```
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel
$spreadSheetData = Import-Excel "C:\Users\,,,\Documents\Book2.xlsx" -HeaderName "Name"

foreach($row in $spreadSheetData) {
$var = $row.Name  
$Apath = Test-Path "C:\Users\,,,\Documents\Staff Photos\New\$var.jpg", "C:\Users\,,,\Documents\Staff Photos\New\$var.png", "C:\Users\,,,\Documents\Staff Photos\New\$var.jpeg"
 if ($Apath -eq $False, $false, $false ){ Write-Host $Apath $var }
}
```

Output:

```
True False False Si...
True False False Mo...
True False False Su...
False True False Ma...
True False False Ka...
```

Ideally, none of these should be printed as it should only print it out if all 3 are false.

Comment: you're trying to compare 2 arrays for equality and arrays are not comparable. you could replace your condition for `if ($Apath -notcontains $true)` tho

Comment: I get the same if ocndition being ignored, except its
False False False Si...
False False False Mo... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the right way to do it, because the right side of -eq gets converted to a string:

```
"False False False" -eq $false,$false,$false

True
```

```
"$($false,$false,$false)"

False False False
```

Compare-object method, since there's no output when two lists are equal.  Note that the order doesn't matter without -syncwindow 0.

```
if (compare-object $false,$false,$false $false,$false,$true) { 'not equal' }

not equal
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Santiago is on the right path. You might need to do `if ($Apath -notcontains $false)`
should only run if none of them are false.
alternatively to make it easier you can do

```
$Apath1 = Test-Path 'yourpath.1'
$Apath2 = Test-Path 'yourpath.2'
$Apath3 = Test-Path 'yourpath.3'

if ($Apath1 -and $Apath2 -and $Apath3)
```

This is a bit more code but it might simplify it a little bit instead of trying to compare to an array

Comment: @lit you're right thanks, I edited it. I was working on a python script at the same time as I  was answering this